# trying to create a character limit on username but it is skipping the strlen if statement

Tags: php

Im trying to create a registration page which worked fine but a friend of mine pointed out the logout button becomes unreachable if a name is at a certain length so i tried fixing it by setting a character limit on the username but it just seems to skip the whole if statement i wrote down here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
//include database
include 'database.php';

$email = $_POST['email'];
$username = $_POST['usernames'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$hashedpass = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

if (empty($email) || empty($username) || empty($password)) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = "Vul alles in";
    header('Location: ../registration.php');
} else if (strlen($username) > 25) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = "Gebruikersnaam te lang";
    header('Location: ../registration.php');
} else {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = ?");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $username, PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt->rowCount() == 0) {
        $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO login (username, password) VALUES (:username, :password)");
        $sql->bindParam('username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sql->bindParam('password', $hashedpass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sql->execute();
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header('Location: ../index.php');
    } else {
        $_SESSION['error'] = "Gebruikersnaam bestaal al!";
        header('Location: ../registration.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably not related to your problem, but I would recommend (although it is a stylistic preference), whenever you do a server redirect, to follow that immediately with an `exit`. By doing that, it becomes easier to see that you can actually remove your `else` and just have two `if` blocks. You can repeat similarly with the last nested block. Less indentation is usually easier to read, debug and reason about.

Comment: you should use exit; after outputting a location header. header('Location: ../registration.php'); Header by itself doesn't stop the script running

Comment: @ChrisHaas i posted the answer and it does look nicer indeed it also helped me resolve the issue.

Comment: @bumperbox also thanks for pointing the exit() out :D!

Comment: The only problem that I see is `25` versus `255`. There is no `else if`elogic error nor is there any reason to believe that not calling `exit()` is causing trouble.  All of the `header()` calls are perfectly isolated within their conditional branch.  In other words, there is no bleed-through to a subsequence portion of code after calling `header()`.

Answer (score 0):

Hey thanks alot for the help the exit()'s helped me resolve this issue, code:

```
<?php
session_start();
//include database
include 'database.php';

$email = $_POST['email'];
$username = $_POST['usernames'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$hashedpass = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

if (empty($email) || empty($username) || empty($password)) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = "Vul alles in";
    header('Location: ../registration.php');
    exit();
}  
if (strlen($username) > 25) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = "Gebruikersnaam te lang";
    header('Location: ../registration.php');
    exit();
}
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $username, PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);
$stmt->execute();
if ($stmt->rowCount() == 0) {
    $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO login (username, password) VALUES (:username, :password)");
    $sql->bindParam('username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql->bindParam('password', $hashedpass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql->execute();
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    header('Location: ../index.php');
} else {
    $_SESSION['error'] = "Gebruikersnaam bestaal al!";
    header('Location: ../registration.php');
}
```

Comment: I’m glad you were able to solve your problem! I’d recommend also updating your other `header` usages to include an `exit`, too.

Comment: @Chris do you actually see anything broken in the original code? I don't. (Besides the `25` versus `255` problem.)  It is not necessary to `exit()` if there is no more code in the file.

Comment: @mickmackusa, nothing broken, but I’m also not taking it for granted that this is the entire file. Regardless, as my original comment on the question stated, it is just a personal preference, but the OP later agreed that they also thought it made their code nicer, so I was just pointing out another opportunity.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is right before your eyes :) your elseif statement is written as (else if) instead of (elseif). Fix that and see if it works ;)

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php else if and elseif are the same in php when using curly brackets

Comment: @bumperbox Yes! its the same thing, but note that (else if) only executes when the preceding statement is false (just as in his case) unlike (elseif) which executes regardless of the if condition being met

Comment: PSR-12 guidelines state that `else if` is a violation of not using curly braces.  In PHP, `elseif` should always be one word.  That said, the space between words does not break the intended logic.  This answer is incorrect.